# Django manytomany with value

Tags: python, django, field

Source example:

```
class Amenities(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=300)
    value = models.BooleanField("Bool",default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "amenities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Property(models.Model):     
    title = models.CharField("Name category", max_length=300)
    amenities = models.ManyToManyField(Amenities)
```

I wanna to create a list Aminities. Merge Amenities table with the Rent table and for each row add a value.

Like in picture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i need is:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany
Easy solution.